# Brightness slider gone, and the brightness is constantly jittering

Tags: 13.10, screen, brightness

I've just installed a clean version of 13.10 on my MSI U123.
Before I've used 12.4 without a hitch.
As soon as I entered the brightness and lock settings window the brightness starts to flicker and jitter uncontrollably and the brightness slider is gone. The function keys still work, but the jittering is "stronger" and will keep on jittering.

Also the "brightness changed" notification doesn't go away, but I guess that's intentional seeing as how the brightness is constantly changing.

[image: http://i43.tinypic.com/2hfidme.jpg]

[image: http://i40.tinypic.com/5knc7o.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

This is not an direct answer to your question, but is a workaround.

Download the .deb file of Brightness Controller from http://lordamit.github.io/Brightness/. Though It is in Software Center but still is not available for Ubuntu 13.10 (We are working on a newer version which will be submitted for all supported versions of Ubuntu within a month).
[image: Screenshot 1]

It supports controlling brightness up to two displays.

Comment: This does it via software rather than actually reducing the brightness of the backlight. It is a work around as such, but not a very useful one unfortunately.